# How can I use a list to avoid repeating 'and/or' operators over and over again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

My code looks something like:

```
if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 4 or x == 5 or x == 6:
    print('Text')
```

So I'm wondering if I can combine all those conditions into a list, so something like:

```
if x == {1,2,3,4,5,6}:
    print('Text')
```

to make my code cleaner and also it's less work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator and a set of values instead:

```
if x in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}:
    print('Text')
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a set instead of a list/dict. "in" operator is O(1) for a set and O(n) for others. Improves performance by quite a lot for larger lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any iterable (*list*, *tuple*, *dictionary*) for storing the `x` values and check whether the variable is in the iterable or not using `in`.

---

For your specific case, you can use:

```
In [56]: x = 4
In [57]: if x in range(1, 7):
    ...:     print('yes')
    ...:     
yes
```

Comment: `1 <= x <= 6` is  faster than `x in range(...)`  - about five times faster when I profiles with `timeit.timeit`.